# GeoJSON or VectorTiles for dynamic large dataset - when to use which one?

Tags: postgis, geojson, web-mapping, vector-tiles, pg-tileserv

Assuming that the goal is to develop a web application with a static basemap (can be raster tiles) and multiple layers, which:

- are stored in a PostGIS database
- have a big amount of features
- include about 10-20 attributes
- have to be requested dynamically by users

With these assumptions in mind, which data format works better: GeoJSON or Vector Tiles? In what situations would you prefer one over the other and why?

Thoughts:

- Vector Tiles, because of the binary format, are smaller in size than GeoJSON?
- Vector Tiles might not be requested faster, because although they are only delivered for the requested tiles, for GeoJSON a BBOX could be sent.
- Crunchy data provides pg_tileserv (Vector Tiles) and pg_featureserv (GeoJSON) already providing the HTTP endpoints and an API how to request features (e.g. handling the BBOX query for GeoJSON data).

Comment: I suggest making comparative tests because you know best the data that you have. Vector tiles can be slower to create but usually they are delivered from a cache. If the service is dynamic then cache does not help. Vector tiles are always changing the geometries so if that matters, use GeoJSON that can deliver the geometries and coordinates unaltered.